# Reference type and object type

Tags: java, reference-type, object-type

I'm mentoring a colleagues OCA-Java 7 Certification. He's also attending a course and did a preparation exam there. One of the questions was about reference and object types. Here is the code:

```
package com.company;

public class Vehicle implements Mobile {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Truck theTruck = new Truck();
    Vehicle theVehicle = theTruck;
    Mobile theMobile = theVehicle;
  }
}

class Truck extends Vehicle {
}

interface Mobile {
}
```

The question: What is is the reference type and the object type of `theMobile`?

And here are the choices:

- A Reference type is "Mobile", object type is "Mobile"
- B Reference type is "Truck", object type is "Truck"
- C Reference type is "Mobile", object type is "Truck"
- D Reference type is "Car", object type is "Mobile"

Answer B is marked as the correct answer...but IMHO answer C is right. Who's wrong here?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Whats wrong here ?

Printed answer in your book/material is wrong here :p

Reference variable `theMobile` of type `Mobile` is referring to object of type `Truck`.

So answer 3 is correct, Reference type is `Mobile` and Object type is `Truck`.

You can check object type with `theMobile.getClass()` which will return `Truck` and reference type is what statically declared in your code, which is `Mobile` in your `Mobile theMobile = ...` declaration.

Answer (score 10):

I've never seen those terms used for this, but I assume they mean declared type vs run time type.

```
Mobile theMobile = theVehicle;
```

The variable has a declared type of `Mobile` and a run time type of `Truck`. Answer C is correct.

The terms *reference type* refer to any type in Java that is not a primitive and not the `null` type.

Comment: The term "reference type" doesn't just refer to "compile-time" types.  A variable of type `Mobile[]` may hold a reference to a one-element array of type `Vehicle[]`, which would in turn hold a reference to a `Truck`.  The type of reference stored in the array would be `Vehicle`, although the only type known at compile time would be `Mobile`.

Answer (score 4):

There is another thumb rule which is handy, and it goes something like this

```
Class_Name Reference_Variable = new Class_Constructor()
```

[image]

So the piece of code

```
Truck theTruck = new Truck();
Vehicle theVehicle = theTruck;
Mobile theMobile = theVehicle;
```

Here -

> **theTruck** is the "reference variable" of type Truck and "Object Type" of Truck
>
> **theVehicle** is the "reference varible" of type Vehicle and "Object Type" of theTruck "reference", which is, Truck
>
> **theMobile** is the **"reference variable" of type Moble** and "**Object Type" of** theVehicle "reference", which is, **Truck**.

So **Option C** is the correct answer.

Comment: Are you sure 'Object of Type' can refer to both the Declared type and also the Object type? I thought Object of Type would always refer to the object itself, thus the 'Object type'.

Answer (score 3):

`theTruck` is a `Truck`. Since `Truck` extends `Vehicle`, when you say `Vehicle theVehicle = theTruck` `theVehicle` is still a `Truck`. Same thing when you do `Mobile theMobile = theVehicle`: Your object is still a `Truck`.

EDIT: According to another answer, C is correct, because you're referring to your `Truck` as a `Mobile`.

Answer (score 1):

Thumb Rule

> a super class reference variable can be assign to subclass Object

According to that Rule `Mobile theMobile`can be Assigned to `vehicle` or `Truck`

As vehicle is Not instantiated , it is also a reference type

So Answer `3 C Reference type is "Mobile", object type is "Truck"`
is correct

Answer (score 0):

Answer `C.  Reference type is "Mobile", object type is "Truck"` is correct.  While the reference points to a Truck object at the moment, it can be moved to point to any object that implements Mobile or a sub-interface thereof.  Thus, the reference type is Mobile.